# Copying Metadata Between Files in iTunes

Tags: itunes, metadata

A while back, I converted some AVI files to .m4v files that would be playable on my iPhone. When I play these files on my PC using iTunes the quality is terrible because the resolution is so low. My solution is to convert the AVI's using Handbrake using the "Universal" preset; it works like a charm and I can now watch them both on my PC and iPhone.

**The Problem**

I want to import the newly converted files into my iTunes library and be able to copy the metadata (show, season (these are TV episodes) Description, etc) without having to manually copy and paste values from one file to another. Is it possible to just say "copy this file's metadata to this file"?

Comment: According to the iTunes AppleScript dictionary, you can at least get that information from any given track from within a script (assuming you're on a Mac). Someone else will need to help figure out how to apply that systematically.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac OS X? You use Handbrake which I only knew on OS X, but apparently there's also a Windows version, so it's not clear what's your setup.

Comment: Might something like *exiftool* help? It won't to an automatic transfer but you may be able to script it. See http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: I'm using handbrake

Answer (score 1):

This [script](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/download.php?sc=copytinforackstotracks) works for videos too.

Comment: Just realized that it uses Applescript, therefore it only works on Mac. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh my GOD!!!

How did I not know about these!? EPIC WIN.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to do the video file conversions.

The advanced parameter [map_meta_data](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC12) could solve the problem:

```
-map_meta_data outfile:infile
```

will copy the metadata from Input File to the output file.

The following article might help : 
[FFmpeg for Windows Help](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/)